# Adding UITableView SectionIndex A-Z makes UITableViewCell move/change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which is populated with a section index a-z (like the contacts application).
When adding this the `UITableViewCell` (which is a custom one) is moved to the left to make the sectionindex fit.

You get the same "effect" when you are adding a segue between two `viewControllers` and the accessory appears. But then you can easily remove the accessory in the `Storyboard` interface.

I want to just "lay" over the cell instead of pushing it to the left.
Look at the picture below. I want the white to go under the `sectionindex` like it does in the contacts app.

I don't know if there is any code I should provide, in case there is. Let me know.

App is running iOS 6.0.
Not using Auto Layout.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Ok solved this. Using AutoSizing in Storyboard.